# Is it possible to trigger an event on dynamically loaded iframe contents in a document with jquery: on method

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, jquery-on

I would like to add mousemove and keypress events for iframes. The following code works for existing iframes in the page but it won't for dyanamically created frames in the document through javascript.

```
$('iframe').contents().keypress(function(){
         console.log('iframe keypress event fired1');
      });

      $('iframe').contents().mousemove(function(){
        console.log('iframe mousemove event fired2');
     });
```

I wanted to make this work for dynamically created frames after document is loaded. I have copied entire code below.

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Iframe Events Test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
</head>
<body>
<div>Existing Iframe</div>
<input id="btnFrame" type="button" value="Load Dynamic Iframe"/>
<iframe width="200px" height="100px"></iframe>
</body>
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log('document ready event...');
    $('#btnFrame').click(function(){
        console.log('btn click event...');
        console.log($('iframe#dynamic').length);
        if ($('iframe#dynamic').length === 0) {     
            prepareFrame();
        }       
    }); 
});

$(window).on('load', function() {
       $('iframe').on("load", function () {
         // All the contents of the iframe are loaded
         $('iframe').contents().keypress(function(){
            console.log('iframe keypress event fired');
         });
       });
    });


function prepareFrame() {
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("id", 'dynamic');
    ifrm.style.width = "640px";
    ifrm.style.height = "480px";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}

</script>

</html>
```

Comment: Sure, do you have editing privileges on the page within the iframe?

Answer (score 0):

This is because your iframes are not available when you are registering the event listener. You can register your event listener after your view done loading.

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
   $('iframe').on("load", function () {
     // All the contents of the iframe are loaded
     $('iframe').contents().keypress(function(){
        console.log('iframe keypress event fired');
     });
   });
});
```

Comment: It's not working for me, I dont even see the debugger even hitting insde block of window->load. Any other alternative to ($window).on('load')?

Comment: What is the jquery version you are using

Comment: Jquery-3.1.1 is the version

Comment: I have updated the answer, did you try adding a console log just after your `$(window).on('load'` to see whether its working?

Comment: $(window).on('load') works but  $('iframe').on('load') event did n't work when Iframe is loaded through java script.

Comment: Can you update your question with the complete code?

Answer (score 0):

Better approach to get click event using JS
First Get element of Iframe

```
 const iframe = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];
```

Then add one Anchor tag having Id as 'play_video' in HTML and add click event

```
const play = document.getElementById('play_video');
play.click();
```

That's how you will get an event on click of Iframe which dynamically loaded from CMS or Database.